# Why database migration fails in case of blob datatype in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, blob, dbmigrate

I'm trying to create a simple application with Ruby on Rails. I've created this scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold Pic title:string content:blob description:text
```

and when I try to migrate db with `rake db:migrate` I'm getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `blob' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0xb74f8ec4>
```

When I write say `text` instead of `blob` it works normally. So what's the problem with `blob` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The keyword is binary, not blob.

```
rails generate scaffold Pic title:string content:binary description:text
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no keyword blob in rails, you need binary.

```
rails generate scaffold Pic title:string content:binary description:text
```